# Using lambda function

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Is there a way to use lambda function to perform the operation in the image without having to list all the column names?

Comment: try: .agg(["sum"]) it will perform sum() to all the columns

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you want a lambda function for this? If you want to sum all columns, It seems to me that `groupby(...).sum()` should do it.